# Custom Woocommerce Tracking Pixel Not Pulling Values

Tags: php, woocommerce, pixel

I am working on dropping in a tracking pixel for woocommerce and want to pull in the order id and the order value to post onto a 3rd party database via their pixel. I can get the pixel reading on thier end fine at the thank you page, but the values are not coming in for the order id and the order value and being output in the url string. I have just updated the pixel to be:

```
//Tracking pixel for Funker360
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'funker360_pixel' );
function funker360_pixel($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    echo( "<img style='display:none;’ src=\"https://urlinfoforpixel&Order_Id=$order&total=$order_total\">");
}
```

My last iteration of:

```
//Tracking pixel for Funker360
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'funker360_pixel' );
function funker360_pixel($order_id) {
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    echo( "<img style='display:none;’ src=\"https://urlinfoforpixel&Order_Id={$order}&total={$order_total}\">");
}
```

Any help or input on how to grab the order id and order value and add them to the string would be appreciated, I feel like it is close. I just updated the printif to echo as well as the value was not being output via printif.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo "<img style='display:none' src='https://blabla&Order_Id=" . $order->get_id() . "&total=" . $order->get_total() . "'>";
```

I've cleaned the PHP a little to avoid issues with single and double quotes. Also, $order->get_id() will calculate the order ID for you

Comment: Hi businessbloomer, can you explain in a sentence what this code does? (It is pretty obvious but code-only answers are often marked as low quality by the algorithm. Adding a short explanation what you did usually prevents that.

Comment: Will do, sorry about that

Comment: Added some context now

Comment: Thank you, that solved getting the variables into the database!

Comment: Excellent! Please accept the answer if you got time: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work